# How to convert the json data into tyescript format

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

(typescript)

getting the data from mock

```
let dbData = getData (); 
  res.status(200).json({
    data:
    dbData,
   
  });

//mock data

const getData = () => [
  {
    ranktype: '1',
    rankname: '1',
    rankseq:  1,
  },
  {
    ranktype: '2',
    rankname: '2',
    rankseq:  2,
  },
]
```

it works to getting the dataset from the mock data.

---

I would like to get the data from API.

How to construct the same data if I am getting the `api` from JSON object?

API data:

```
{"data":[{"ranktype":"DAY","rankname":"1","rankseq":6,"rankstatus":"ACTIVE"},{"ranktype":"MONTH","rankname":"2","rankseq":2,"rankstatus":"ACTIVE"}]}
```

It is not working if I put the json into typescript array.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new interface for these objects, like that:

```
interface RankDTO {
  ranktype: string;
  rankname: string;
  rankseq: number;
  rankstatus: string;
}
```

Some notes:

1. Pay attention to `"rankstatus"` object property which doesn't exist in your mock data, it must be there.
2. Properties `"ranktype"` and `"rankstatus"` will look better, if you specify them as enums.

Then, when you have created interface correct, just type your mock data:

```
const getData = (): Array<RankDTO> => [ 
  { ranktype: 'DAY', rankname: '1', rankseq: 1, rankstatus: "ACTIVE"}, 
  { ranktype: 'MONTH', rankname: '2', rankseq: 2, rankstatus: "ACTIVE"},
];
```

Don't forget to add `"rankstatus"`.

---

P.S.
Examples of typing using enums:

```
enum RANK_TYPES {
  DAY = 'DAY',
  WEEK = 'WEEK',
  MONTH = 'MONTH',
  YEAR = 'YEAR'
}

enum RANK_STATUS {
  ACTIVE = 'ACTIVE',
  DISABLED = 'DISABLED',
  DRAFT = 'DRAFT'
}

interface RankDTO {
  ranktype: RANK_TYPES;
  rankname: string;
  rankseq: number;
  rankstatus: RANK_STATUS;
}

const getData = (): Array<RankDTO> => [ 
  { ranktype: RANK_TYPES.DAY, rankname: '1', rankseq: 1, rankstatus: RANK_STATUS.ACTIVE}, 
  { ranktype: RANK_TYPES.WEEK, rankname: '2', rankseq: 2, rankstatus: RANK_STATUS.ACTIVE},
];
```

Comment: I wonder how to construct the API JSON data same as the value of "getData = ()", thanks

Comment: const res = await fetch(url);
  const { data }: { data: RankInterface } = await res.json();
  console.log("data");
  console.log(data);

 return data;

Comment: getting the error :

  79 |   res.status(200).json({
  80 |     data:
> 81 |     apiData?.slice(parseInt(start), parseInt(start) + parseInt(size)) ?? [],
     |             ^
  82 |
  83 |   });

-----------------------------------------------------------
 let apiData = fetchData();